# Some clarifications on my understanding of sets

Tags: set-theory

Suppose I have $X = \{\varnothing, \mathbb N, \mathbb Z \}$. Are all nonempty subsets of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ automatically elements of $X$? In particular, is $\mathbb N \cap \mathbb Z$ in $X$? I'm asking because I read somewhere that $\varnothing$ and $\{ \varnothing\}$ are not the same thing. Does it also apply for example to $\mathbb R$ and $\{ \mathbb R\}$?

Comment: Do not "*flatten*" sets in your mind.  Being an element of a set is not the same thing as being an element of an element of a set, or being a subset of an element of a set, etc...  Worded another way, the number of brackets is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $X=\{\emptyset, \mathbb N, \mathbb Z\}$, then that means $X$ is a set with exactly three elements: the empty set, the naturals and the integers. The statement $a\in X$ is therefore true if and only if one of the following three statements is true:

1. $a=\emptyset$.
2. $a=\mathbb N$.
3. $a=\mathbb Z$.

If the three statements above are all false, then $a$ is not an element of $X$.

In particular:

> Are all nonempty subsets of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ automatically elements of $X$?

No. Not all. In fact, only $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ are elemnents of $X$. No other nonempty subsets of $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb N$ are elements of $X$.

> In particular, is $\mathbb N \cap \mathbb Z$ in $X$?

Well, yes, but only because $\mathbb N\cap \mathbb Z = \mathbb N$, and we already know that $\mathbb N\in X$.

---

Also:

> I'm asking because I read somewhere that $\varnothing$ and $\{ \varnothing\}$ are not the same thing.

Well, of course they are not the same thing. $\varnothing$ has zero elements, and $\{\varnothing\}$ has one element, so they cannot be the same set. In fact, it is **always** true that if $A$ is a set, then $A$ and $\{A\}$ will be two different sets.

Comment: Instead of throwing statements around it would be better to give *proof*, proofs will fully remedy OP’s confusion.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku How exactly do you prove a definition? Also, that last paragraph literally contains a proof that $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are not the same set (i.e., they contain a different number of elements).

Comment: “No non empty subsets…” requires proof, it may be trivial for many of us but it may not be for the OP.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku If the OP asks for this proof, I will be happy to provide it.

Comment: Of course, please don’t take my comments as criticising you. I’m just trying to help the OP.